# How can i use https://github.com/odyslam/foundry-upgrades to make upgradable contract?

Tags: solidity, foundry, contract-upgrading

i am making a upgradable contract with foundry. I have deployed and verified the code. I was looking for a substitute for https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades and suddenly got this: https://github.com/odyslam/foundry-upgrades. But i can't figure out how to use this. How to use it?

secondly It is asking to clone and `forge install`, where do i clone it? In my root project directory? Help me on it.

Thirdly as i said i already deployed the contract, do i need to redeploy it with `deployProxy`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Foundry version of the [hardhat-upgrades](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades) provided by the OpenZeppelin team, which can be found here: [openzeppelin-foundry-upgrades](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-foundry-upgrades).
Please refer to the [usage](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-foundry-upgrades?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) section where you'll find the answers for all your questions.